# Array object Group by an element?

Tags: javascript

I have an array object behind

```
var x =[
{'image_url': 'abc.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'eeed.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfsf.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'vccxda.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfdsw.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfsgsfg.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-02-01'}]
```

**I would like to :**

```
var results =[
[
    {'image_url': 'abc.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
    {'image_url': 'sdfsf.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
    {'image_url': 'sdfdsw.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'}
],
[
    {'image_url': 'eeed.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
    {'image_url': 'vccxda.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01'}
],
[
    {'image_url': 'sdfsgsfg.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-02-01'},
] ]
```

Can some one help me create array object?
Thanks all.

Comment: please add the rule for grouping.

Comment: I think he's grouping by `device` and `time`.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and go through this tutorial http://reactivex.io/learnrx/ (the first part is related to vanilla JavaScript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pease Use Below Code :

```js
function groupBy( array , f )
{
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach( function( o )
  {
    var group = JSON.stringify( f(o) );
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push( o );  
  });
  return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
  {
    return groups[group]; 
  })
}

var list =[
{'image_url': 'abc.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'eeed.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfsf.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'vccxda.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfdsw.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfsgsfg.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-02-01'}];
var result = groupBy(list, function(item)
{
  return [item.device,item.time];
});

console.dir(result);
```

Comment: Please check in your console for your array.  my function is group by any field

Comment: its group by time and device

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103692/discussion-between-tai-nguyen-and-javedrathod).

Answer (score 2):

With plain Javascript, I suggest to use a function with a temporary object and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> The `forEach()` method executes a provided function once per array element.

```js
var x = [{ 'image_url': 'abc.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01' }, { 'image_url': 'eeed.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01' }, { 'image_url': 'sdfsf.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01' }, { 'image_url': 'vccxda.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01' }, { 'image_url': 'sdfdsw.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01' }, { 'image_url': 'sdfsgsfg.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-02-01' }],
    result = function (data, group) {
        var r = [],
            o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            var k = group.map(function (b) { return a[b]; }).join('|');
            if (!(k in o)) {
                o[k] = [];
                r.push(o[k]);
            }
            o[k].push(a);
        });
        return r;
    }(x, ['device', 'time']);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: Ya these is the raw js solution. However to complete those type of tasks,  I think peoples should consider to use Underscore/Lodash

Answer (score 2):

With lodash:

```
y = _.values(_.groupBy(x, e => [e.device, e.time]))
```

If you don't want a library, these functions are easy to mimic:

```
groupBy = function(a, f) {
    return a.reduce((o, e) => {
        var k = f(e);
        o[k] = (o[k] || []).concat(e);
        return o;
    }, {});
}

values = function(o) {
    return Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k]);
}

y = values(groupBy(x, e => [e.device, e.time]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Underscore allow you to do that pretty easily:

```
var sortedIdDevice = _.groupBy(x, function(ite){return ite.device});
```

**sortedIdDevice:**

```
{1: Array[4], 2: Array[2]}
```

Would be easier for you to manipulate those sorted array with the object.

Else, you could do :

```
//grouping by device
var sortedIdDevice = _.values(_.groupBy(x, function(ite){return ite.device}));
```

Give you the format you want:

```
[Array[4], Array[2]]
```

Passing array to GroupBy allow you to group by multiple fields:

```
//grouping by device and date
var sortedIdDevice = _.values(_.groupBy(x, function(ite){return [ite.device, ite.time]}));
```

Return exactly what you want:

```
[Array[3], Array[2], Array[1]]
```

Comment: I agree, the input isn't exactly the same, I dunno if it deserve downvote tho.

Comment: @NinaScholz I also gave the exact output

Answer (score 1):

A vanilla js approach using the array reduce function is

```
var x =[
{'image_url': 'abc.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'eeed.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfsf.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'vccxda.jpg', 'device': 2, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfdsw.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-01-01'},
{'image_url': 'sdfsgsfg.jpg', 'device': 1, 'time': '2015-02-01'}]
var mapping = [];
result = x.reduce(function (prev, current) {
    var key = current.device + '|' + current.time;
    var index = mapping.indexOf(key); 
    if ( index != -1) {
        prev[index].push(current);
    } else {
        mapping.push(key);
        prev.push([current]);
    }
    return prev;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```